# A bad GET request from a server?

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, get

I am trying to send a simple GET request to Amazon which **works** from any browser, and also looks the same at `hurl.it` , but i get a respond with  a bad request.

The request is being sent from a hardware device , and it looks like this when it sent :

```
 GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
 Host:XX.XX.2XX.1X
 Content-Type:application/json
 Connection:close
```

respond is this :

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 16 Oct 2015 13:58:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 320
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
```

What is wrong with it ? (the server is a simple index.php file,no more headers )

Comment: Please show your index.php

Comment: Hey,thanks a lot. My index.php is not relevant, as i wrote, it works from any browser with xx.xxxx.xx/index.php

Comment: There's quite a few things that could be happening. Without seeing your index.php it's very hard to tell. Some common headers that you omitted are `Accept`, as well as `User-Agent`. Further, HTTP requests without a body should not have a `Content-Type` header. Try spoofing some requests missing various headers to see if your script is unhappy with it.

Comment: First guess is that the line endings are wrong, something other than `\r\n`.